# What are all the things we can do with telnet?

Tags: networking

I would like to know all the things that can be done with telnet, currently i use it to determine if a remote machine is listening on some specific port like this 
telnet [machine] [port].
any ideas please

Comment: I hate it when people close questions like this.  As a developer, knowing how to use telnet AS A DIAGNOSTIC AID for developers is a key skill.

Answer (score 7):

Look at telnet as basically opening a socket to another machine on a port.

You can log into another machine (not securely) using it.  If you know the SMTP protocol, you can send mail with it.  If you know how to formulate an HTTP request, you can even make HTTP requests with it and get back a HTTP response stream.  It's a lovely tool.

Comment: If you're very, *very* patient and good at math, you could even SSH with it.

Answer (score 2):

It can be useful in debugging many application level protocols. For example:

```
% telnet stackoverflow.com http
HEAD / HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com
```

returns the HTTP headers of stackoverflow.com front page.

Though netcat (`man 1 nc`) is a bit more versatile in these kinds of tasks.

Comment: I was trying to do this, but I guess my proxy blocked me:)

Answer (score 2):

You can interact with an SMTP server to send mail:

```
telnet somemailserver.somedomain.com 25
HELO somesender.somesenddomain.com
MAIL FROM: somebody@somewhere.com
RECPT TO: somerecipient@somewhere.com
DATA
Type message now.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

FTP, HTTP I already tried.  You can telnet to a web server to work with the headers themselves etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to your mail server and send an email using telnet.

Telnet to hostname on port 25
HELO your_domain_name or whatever
MAIL FROM:you@hostname.com 
RCPT TO:them@someplace_else.com

DATA

hit ENTER
QUIT